# Run Keyword If Robotframework

Tags: python, if-statement, robotframework

Was Iterating inside array and imposing Run Keyword If

```
    Run Keyword If      "${text}" == "CPNUMBER *******"    Append To List  ${textList}     CP
...  Else If     "${text}" == "FNAME **** ****"   Append To List  ${textList}     FNAME TONY STARK
```

And the output was

```
['Create List', 'FNAME **** ****', 'CPNUMBER 1111111', 'Else If', '"${text}" == "FNAME **** ****"', 'Append To List', [...], 'FNAME TONY STARK']
```

The first two array are correct however the whole else if validation is appended on my list. How can I Filter these names and append to my list.

Im using RBF 3.1+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Else If` should be in uppercase. In this case, the whole `Else If     "${text}" == "FNAME **** ****"   Append To List  ${textList}     FNAME TONY STARK` is considered as `*values`, so it is executed as `Append To List  ${textList}     CP    Else If     "${text}" == "FNAME **** ****"   Append To List  ${textList}     FNAME TONY STARK`. Refer to [Run Keyword If](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If) to see how to do else if.

You should try

```
    Run Keyword If      "${text}" == "CPNUMBER *******"    Append To        List  ${textList}     CP
    ...  ELSE IF     "${text}" == "FNAME **** ****"   Append To List  ${textList}     FNAME TONY STARK
```